# почему не запускается jar файл? An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file

Tags: java, консоль, jar

Создал архив jar при помощи ANT. Код сборки:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="HelloWorld" default="run">

    <!-- define names of directories -->
    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="build" location="build"/>
    <property name="classes" location="${build}/classes"/>
    <!-- define all targets -->
    <target name="hello">
        <echo>Hello, World!</echo>
    </target>
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" includeAntRuntime="false"/>
    </target>
    <target name="run" depends="hello, compile">
        <java classname="${ant.project.name}" classpath="${classes}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="package" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="${build}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main–Class" value="${ant.project.name}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

</project>
```

Создался файл `HelloWorld.jar` с манифестом `MANIFEST.MF`  с кодом:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.10.1
Created-By: 1.8.0_131-b11 (Oracle Corporation)
Main–Class: HelloWorld
```

Теперь когда от руки в консоли от места где находится папки `SRC` и `BUILD` запускаю:

```
java -jar build/HelloWorld.jar
```

то появляется следующая ошибка:

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file build/HelloWorld.jar
```

переменные окружения перепроверил `JAVA_HOME` и `PATH` указан путь на папку bin из JDK1.8

Помогите разобраться, почему на запускается файл `HelloWorld`?

Comment: манифест лежит по правильному пути `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`?

Comment: да, вот здесь он находится:

Comment: C:\Users\Восход\IdeaProjects\EPAMAUTUMN2017\build\HelloWorld.zip\META-INF

Comment: причем если указывать путь через -cp то все работает:                     java -cp HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld

Comment: Думал может потому, что один из каталогов на русском перенес в другой каталог: /d/XXXX/build. Ничего не изменилось

Comment: собрал в ручную jar cf HelloWolrld.jar HelloWold . Архив собрался, затем сам в манифесте указал Main-Class: HelloWorld. И затем запустил java -jar HelloWorld. Все работает, но через ант после сборки ничего не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в следующем: в конфигурации сборки в строке

```
<attribute name="Main–Class" value="${ant.project.name}"/>
```

символ `–` - это не дефис, а *короткое тире*. Поэтому данный атрибут не читается при попытке запуска. Скорее всего дело в том, что данная конфигурация была откуда-то скопирована в таком виде.

Чтобы решить проблему - исправьте в этой строке тире на дефис.

Answer (score 1):

В общем не знаю, что произошло(((( Но я в xml файле переписал заново от клавиатуры имя атрибута в манифесте (Стер "Main-Class" и снова написал"Main-Class") и о чудо всё прекрасно заработало.
И еще в вывложенном xml файле копирую имя атрибута "Main-Class" и вставляю его в свой xml , очищаю, снова собираю джарник, запускаю и опять выбрасывает ошибку!!! Переписываю снова от клавиатуры очищаю, собираю, запускаю - все работает. Магия какая-то(((